# Laravel - How to properly code in this situation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a website that allows users to log in and out at specific locations. When the main page is loaded, I pull data from the DB, process it in the controller and then send it to the view. I have quite a lot of redundant code in my controller methods.

How can I achieve the same result by using a class to do the pull from DB and process part?

Comment: Write a class that does what you do on every controller and inject it into the `__construct` method?

Comment: Please provide some relevant code snippet! What are you getting at for the time being... ;-)

Comment: I don't have all the code yet or at least what I have would not make sense to post. I noticed while writing that I keep on repeating myself and started doing more research on better practices.

Comment: It seems "view composer" can help you.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers
What you think ?

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan, can you be a bit more specific? How can 'view composer' can help? I have no clue.

Comment: For specific answer I need specific question ;)
But if I understand right, you need load and bind data to view not from controller.
If so, here is what view composer do ...

View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is created. If you have data that you want bound to a given view each time that view is created throughout your application, a view composer can organize that code into a single location.

This solution also can be very helpful if you need bind same data to different views.

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan, I think I put a quite specific question. My question was related to proper coding when using DB, controller, models and views in Laravel. I tend to put too much code in the controllers and always breakin the SOLID principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike [Action Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) in the Zend Framework,  Laravel doesn't (to my knowedge) have a specific preferred way of keeping your controllers "thin".  When I start noticing redundant code in my Laravel controller, I usually abstract the redundant code into a single protected method on the controller -- one that doesn't rely on controller state.

When my controllers start developing too many of these helper methods, I create stand alone PHP helper classes, and refactor those protected methods into a public method on the stand alone class, with a one to one relationship between my protected helper methods and help class (i.e. each class does one single thing).  If I start noticing redundant behavior between the helper classes, I create a base helper where I can stash this functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. You've just simplified the SOLID principles I am currently learning. I am learning and yes I could use the helper functions inside the controller, but just for the purpose of learning something new I wanna do it via the SOLID principles way. So, I should have: the controller pulls data via Model defined functions from the DB, I then use a helper class to process data, another helper class to format data, and then I send it to the view to be displayed. Does that sound SOLID?

Comment: @Cristian It's pretty easy to look at any code and, with a little knob turn, show how it could be **less** solid, or show how it could be more SOLID. The only way to get a good feel for this stuff is to write your code, write your tests, and learn what sort of patterns make for harder to test code.